# Annotating an equation - differences

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

In trying to annotate an equation with the package `annotate-equations`. Most of the time things work all right and every once in a while it dislocates a piece of the equation inapropriately, like the equal sign on the second one:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}

\begin{document}
\[
a \tikzmarknode{node1}{=} b
\]
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below}{node1}{change of variables}

\[
\int_0^{\infty}F_X(x)dx =\int_0^{\infty}F_X(-x)dx \tikzmarknode{node2}{=} \int^0_{-\infty}F_X(x)dx.
\]
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below}{node2}{change}
\end{document}
```

[image: change in the position of sign]

Is there a way one can control this? I scoured the (very short) manual with no luck.

Comment: `\tikzmarknode` is smart enough to smuggle the math-mode options inside the node that gets created but it will loose any surroundings. You will need to use `\tikzmarknode{<name>}{{}={}}` to get the same spacing (which basically does the same as `\mathrel` but from inside.) I'd maybe use an `outer ysep` for the node sp that the arrow doesn't end so close to the bars of the `=` sign but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Of course, you can define your own macro for that `\newcommand*\tmrel[3][]{\tikzmarknode[#1]{#2]{{}#3{}}` and then just use `\tmrel{node1}{=}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `\mathrel` around the `\tikzmarknode`:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}

\begin{document}
\[
a \mathrel{\tikzmarknode{node1}{=}} b
\]
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below}{node1}{change of variables}

\[
\int_0^{\infty}F_X(x)dx =\int_0^{\infty}F_X(-x)dx \mathrel{\tikzmarknode{node2}{=}} \int^0_{-\infty}F_X(x)dx.
\]
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below}{node2}{change}
\end{document}
```

The way spacing works in math mode is explained in section 23.3 / 23.6 in TeX by topic / page 154 / 170 in TeXbook, you should be able to understand why `\mathrel` is needed given that.

Comment: Any reason why ``annotate-equations`` would not do that by itself? It seems very basic after the reading of the TeXbook.

Comment: @TeXApprentice Let's see how basic it is... • read the argument • check if it consist of exactly one token • check its `\meaning` to see if it's a mathchardef and from that determine which math class it is, and if the token is a single letter/other catcode character then check its mathcode. Doesn't sound so basic now, does it?

Comment: I understand. It seems to be a very buggy package, if the annotation happens at the btottom of a page you have all sorts of malfunctioning as well as arrows interfering with the formula, etc ... I'll  put it aside and try again in a few months. Mant thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hi @TeXApprentice, this is my first-ever LaTeX package and I'm aware it's not perfect. If you have any bug reports, please open an issue on the Git repository: https://github.com/st--/annotate-equations/issues - I can't promise I'll figure out how to fix it, but I'd happily try to help!

Comment: It is, in fact, the easieast way to annotate a formula, so only a few tips and tricks on the manual should do for now, but it would be really nice to see package grow.

Comment:   I would happily accept pull requests that improve the documentation, make the code more robust or easier to use, and perhaps even add features:)